# Changing the extrusion opacity of 3D object in Photoshop CS 6 Extended

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, cs6

How does one change the opacity of the extrusion for a 3D object in Photoshop CS 6 Extended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control-Click (Mac) or Right-Click (Windows) and adjust the Opacity slider for the Extrusion Materials.

Opacity can also be found on the Properties Panel for 3D objects.

[image: extrusion]

Comment: There is also the Texture Map which will allow you to create a Transparency Mask (which works like other Masks in Photoshop using Grayscale values to change to offset the opacity value).  Use the Texture/Folder icon (next to the 43% Opacity value) to make a new texture, the Edit the Texture (and when you open/edit it you may want to use 3D > Create Painting Overlay > Wireframe to see where the extruded shapes UVs (paintable areas) are).